# MacOS Quartz Event Tap listening to wrong events

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

I am trying to intercept mouse move events using the `CGEvent.tapCreate(tap:place:options:eventsOfInterest:callback:userInfo:)` method as shown below:

```
let cfMachPort = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap, 
                                   place: CGEventTapPlacement.headInsertEventTap, 
                                   options: CGEventTapOptions.defaultTap, 
                                   eventsOfInterest:CGEventMask(CGEventType.mouseMoved.rawValue), 
                                   callback: {(eventTapProxy, eventType, event, mutablePointer) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? in event
    print(event.type.rawValue)   //Breakpoint
    return nil
}, userInfo: nil)

let runloopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfMachPort!, 0)

let runLoop = RunLoop.current
let cfRunLoop = runLoop.getCFRunLoop()
CFRunLoopAddSource(cfRunLoop, runloopSource, CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode)
```

I pass as event type `eventsOfInterest` `mouseMoved` events with a raw value of 5 [as seen in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventtype/mousemoved). But for some reason my `print()` is not executed unless I click with the mouse. Inspecting the send mouse event in the debugger gives me a raw value of 2, which according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventtype/leftmouseup) is a `leftMouseUp` event.

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent/1454426-tapcreate) for `CGEvent.tapCreate(tap:place:options:eventsOfInterest:callback:userInfo:)` it says:

*Event taps receive key up and key down events [...]*

So it seems like the method ignores `mouseMoved` events in general?! But how am I supposed to listen to `mouseMoved` events? I am trying to prevent my cursor (custom cursor) from being replaced (for example when I hover over the application dock at the bottom of the screen).

Comment: No, sadly not. Apart from the fact, that the above API describes a legacy API, I need to catch events outside of my application scope. So I need a more low level method to catch mouse events.

Comment: On what version of macOS are you testing? Is your app sandboxed? Either way, your app may need to be granted user permission to control the UI.

Comment: @KenThomases I am testing on 10.15.2 and the app is not sandboxed. I gave accessibility and screen recording allowances.

Comment: @KenThomases the code sample as given will actually just crash if accessibility permission is not granted; because `cfMachPort` will be nil

Comment: @TheNextman I cant find anything named `CGEventMaskBit` on Swift. I am using `CGEventMask(CGEventType.mouseMoved.rawValue)` to get an UInt64. Which is according to the documentation correct. I also can't find any `kCGEventMask*` like `kCGEventMaskForAllEvents`.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventmask

Comment: It's not correct, because `CGEventMask` needs a bitmask, not a constant(s). I posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bitshift the `CGEventType` value used to create the `CGEventMask` parameter. In Objective-C, there is a macro to do this: [CGEventMaskBit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventmaskbit?language=objc).

From the `CGEventMask` documentation:

> to form the bit mask, use the CGEventMaskBit macro to convert each constant into an event mask and then OR the individual masks together

I don't know the equivalent mechanism in swift; but the macro itself looks like this:

`*/ #define CGEventMaskBit(eventType) ((CGEventMask)1 << (eventType))`

In your example, it's sufficient to just manually shift the argument; e.g.

`eventsOfInterest:CGEventMask(1 << CGEventType.mouseMoved.rawValue),`

I would point out that the code example given in the question is a little dangerous; as it creates a default event tap and then drops the events rather than allowing them to be processed. This messes up mouse click handling and it was tricky to actually terminate the application using the mouse. Anyone running the example could set the event tap type to `CGEventTapOptions.listenOnly` to prevent that.

Comment: like I mentioned above I am trying to prevent my cursor from beeing changed when I hover over the dock. I now tried to create an event tap for the pid of my dock. But when I use `CGEventTapOptions.defaultTap` and return nil, it still seems like my events are forwarded. I have tried for like 2 days now to prevent cursor updates over the dock and I have no idea how to. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think blocking events is the solution (I also saw your other question and not sure it was really a duplicate). If it was me I would try to use CoreGraphics private API to completely hide the system cursor and just draw my own: https://github.com/jamesarosen/iTerm2/blob/master/CGSInternal/CGSCursor.h

Comment: I don't know how I would go about that? And if I hide the system cursor how could I draw my one? Just using a view and placing it at the same position?

Comment: Well that header has a function hide the cursor, I'm not sure if it works or not. " how could I draw my one? Just using a view and placing it at the same position?" - pretty much. I never tried something like this before, just telling you what I would try if I was you. Good luck!

Comment: But if I use for example an NSWindow that for my content, I need to deactivate the `x` and `-` button to get a window. As far as I know this goes against apples user interface guidelines. Any ideas on how to comply? I am trying to develop something similar to [this](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/pikka-color-picker/id1195076754?l=en&mt=12).

Comment: Ah, I see. You should make your app create a borderless, transparent `NSWindow` and size it to overlay the whole screen. You can find how to do this pretty easily, there are lots of question on SO. Now you can do what you like with the cursor or draw your own.

Comment: You'll need to set the level of your window to be higher than normal. If your app will be the active one, you can set custom presentation options to even hide the dock and/or menu bar (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/presentationoptions)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207368/discussion-between-j-unruh-and-thenextman).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to listen for `mouseMove` global events (tested with Xcode 11.2+, macOS 10.15)

```
// ... say in AppDelegate

var globalObserver: Any!
var localObserver: Any!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    globalObserver = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .mouseMoved) { event in
        let location = event.locationInWindow
        print("in background: {\(location.x), \(location.y)}")
    }

    localObserver = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .mouseMoved) { event in
        let location = event.locationInWindow
        print("active: {\(location.x), \(location.y)}")
        return event
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Sadly `addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)` does not allow for events to be altered. In addition I don't get any events interesting events when hovering over the dock that I could use to stop the cursor from updating. So this solution is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There's another thing incorrect in your code, although you might be lucky and it isn't normally causing a problem.

As documented for the mode parameter to `CFRunLoopAddSource`: "Use the constant kCFRunLoopCommonModes to add source to the set of objects monitored by all the common modes."

That third parameter should instead be `CFRunLoopMode.commonModes`.
What you have, `CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode` aka `kCFRunLoopDefaultMode`, is instead for use when calling `CFRunLoopRun`.